# Showing two simultaneously Activities (one smaller), the bigger one doesn't listen to finger events

Tags: android, android-activity

I am showing two activities, one activitie bigger than the other. I'm doing it with this:
http://iserveandroid.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/how-to-set-heightwidth-for-activity-or.html

**I'm not using fragments, i'm not using tabs.**

The bigger activity haves some buttons and the smaller activity also haves some buttons.

The bigger activity launchs the smaller activity, and then, the bigger activity stops listening for finger events (touch on the screen).

It is possible to solve this?

I need that the two activities can listen to touch events.

Thanks

EDIT: maybe this can be solved with the flag splitTouch but it is only compatible since Android 3.0, and i need to make this on android 2.2 at least...

Comment: showing two activities?  Do you mean fragments...?  Or two activities in a tab group?  How are you "showing two activities"

Comment: @edthethird i believe he is showing one styled as a dialog.. hence the "smaller activity" description.

Comment: i edited my question with the way i'm doing it

Comment: I am fairly sure that the `Activity` on the top of the stack has the entire window, no matter how big it is.

Comment: do you have some code to show us what's going on?

Comment: its very simple, the bigger activity is not on the top of the stack now, and is not listening for events. But the smaller activity doesn't have all the size of the screen, then maybe exists a way to listen events with both activities simultaneously. Someone knows it?

Comment: That is what I am saying.  Because the bigger `Activity` is not on the top of the stack it doesn't receive touch events.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That only works for `Honeycomb` or later.

Comment: ooops, i need to make this work on android 2.2 or later

Comment: I would use the v4 compat library and use `Fragments`.  Otherwise the only way I can see to do it, would be to have two `ViewGroup` layouts in the `Activity` and style them so they look like separate activities.

Comment: Thanks techi, did you have a link showing how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :)

I can achieve that adding this code to the activity

```
this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
```

and this code into the activity declaration on the manifest:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

Very simple but very hard to find and not documented solution

Ahhh, and it is compatible since API 1 !!